# Need the highest ID using left join

Tags: php, mysql, left-join, outer-join

I have two tables, 
TABLE 1 has **many** of each client and campaign and is very **large**
TABLE 2 has only **one** of each client and campaign and is **small**.

So I want to get the lastest(highest ID) from TABLE 1 where it matches the client and  campaign in TABLE 2 and only one of each. 
I have tried MAX, and playing with the order by etc, but cant get it working....

The results I get are choosing the **lowest** ID from TABLE 1 (I want **highest**)

```
$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT table1.client,table1.campaign,table1.id 
FROM table1 

   LEFT OUTER JOIN
      table2
   ON     (table2.client = table1.client)
      AND (table2.campaign = table1.campaign )
WHERE (table2.enabled != 'disabled')

group by campaign asc
order by client,campaign,id asc
");
```

Help needed....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM table1
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT MAX(table1.id) AS id FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.client = table1.client AND table2.campaign=table1.campaign and table2.enabled != 'disabled'
GROUP BY table1.client, table1.campaign
) AS m ON m.id = table1.id`

I think that's what you're asking for.  For each combination of client and campaign that exists in each table, it will give you the highest ID in table 1.

Comment: Thank you for the insight, it worked...I see your MAX method was at the beginning of the statement, so I tried this on mine and it worked also.Could not have done this without this bit of information.....      It is now SELECT max(table1.id) as maxid

Comment: @Mikeys4u Great, glad it helped you on your way!

Comment: Just noticed something, The query gets the highest id, but not the rest of the data in that row.

Comment: Ah yeah, that's a classic problem - you need to do an outer query.  In brief, something like `SELECT columns FROM table1 INNER JOIN (SELECT MAX(id) AS id ...) AS m ON m.id = table1.id`

Comment: Still cant find the answer, need to pull all the data from the highest ID in TABLE 1, where client and campaign match in TABLE 2.

Comment: Ok now your the GURU.....does what it says on the tin. I can confirm this works...